# Variable that represents all numbers?

Tags: python

I need to define a variable that contains all possible natural numbers, or at least all numbers from 1 to a million.

I don't want to use the `range` function because it is not applicable for my particular purpose. Is there any other way to define the variable so it can represent, or contain any number after 0?

EDIT:
If I use the `range` while defining the variable it will contain a list of numbers, but I am trying to avoid creating a list.

The program is giving me a number `X` and I don't know which number it is, but I need to have that number `X` represented with the variable `var`

Comment: What is your application? Why doesn't range work?

Comment: `if yournum > 0 and yournum < 1000000:`  # do stuff?

Comment: It would help to provide some context. Can you give some example code, or provide a generic situation/requirements? If we had a good idea of what you were trying to do, perhaps we could provide a better answer/solution for you.

Comment: What does it even *mean* for a variable to "contain all possible natural numbers"? Any variable can represent any number after 0 -- that is why they are called "variables"

Comment: You didn't think through my question, it couldn't be that obvious so therefore it isn't! 
I need to define a variable that contains all numbers, so if you ask if a number (any number) is in the variable the answer would always be yes.

Comment: @NedzadGanic, that's your own fault for asking an unclear question. The obvious answer is to use `range`, but you haven't explained why you think it's unsuitable. Without that information there is no way to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Chris you are right, but I don't know how to explain it more clearly

Comment: @NedzadGanic, you could start by explaining why you don't think `range` is a good fit. Next, what do you mean when you say "so if you ask if a number is in the variable the answer would be yes"? `if some_number in my_variable`? ShadowRanger's answer passes that test.

Comment: @Chris 'range' gives me the list of numbers, but I am trying to avoid assigning a list to the variable. I am a total newbie so I don't know if there is a simple way to do it

Comment: @NedzadGanic, as ShadowRanger's answer says, in Python 3.2 and later [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is very efficient. It does _not_ return a list, but rather a range object. "The advantage of the `range` type over a regular `list` or `tuple` is that a `range` object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the `start`, `stop` and `step` values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed)." His second example covers earlier versions of Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.2 and higher, representing a container with all integers from 1 to a million is correctly done with `range`:

```
>>> positive_nums_to_1M = range(1, 1000001)
>>> 1 in positive_nums_to_1M
True
>>> 1000000 in positive_nums_to_1M
True
>>> 0 in positive_nums_to_1M
False
```

It's extremely efficient; the numbers in the range aren't actually generated, instead the membership (or lack thereof) is computed mathematically.

If you need some equivalent object that supports any positive integer, or need it in Python 2.x, you'll have to write your own class, but it's not hard:

```
from operator import index

class natural_num_range(object):
    def __init__(self, maxnum=None):
        if maxnum is not None:
            maxnum = index(maxnum)  # Ensure a true native int (or long)
        self.maxnum = maxnum

    def __contains__(self, x):
        try:
             x = index(x)
        except TypeError:
             return False
        return x >= 1 and (self.maxnum is None or x < self.maxnum)
```

That does something similar to `range`, but without supporting a `start` or `step`, and not requiring a `stop`, so you can do constant time membership tests:

```
>>> natural = natural_num_range()
>>> all(i in natural for i in range(1, 10000000, 10000))
True
>>> any(i in natural for i in range(-100000000, 0, 10000))
False
```